# Why should hibernate query return a List of Optionals?

Tags: java, hibernate, option-type

I have been told that the standard for hibernate queries is to return each object wrapped in an Optional even when the return value is a List like so -

```
  List<Optional<XEntity>> findAllByStatus(String status);
```

It makes complete sense that a single object should be wrapped in an Optional but I don't understand the reasoning when it is a list of objects (with a possible exception for a custom findAll() with an un-sanitized db). If there is a null object, then it won't be picked up by the query, and if no objects correspond to the query, then an empty List would be returned. Adding an Optional for each item seems cumbersome and unnecessary.

I have been told by several people that using Optionals with List is a best practice but none gave me an sufficient explanation and I have been unable to find one via Google plus I have yet to run into a problem while using with

```
  List<XEntity> findAllByStatus(String status);
```

Comment: I have never been told to use a List of Optional, ever. I just can't figure out, as well as you said, which is its utility if it'll be either an empty list or a list filled with non-null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your point that wrapping up in Optional is good choice for single Object but in case of Collections like List,Set etc, it doesn't seems good choice to me. Especially when your API is ensuring to return a Collection object (List object or Empty List) every time. Since  **findAllByStatus(String status)** ensures it will either return  **object(s) or no object** in that case **framework** will ensure to return **Empty List**.
Wrapping up every objects with **Optional** in list as you mentioned is only useful when any of the object in list is **Null**.

I have not seen any issue with  **List findAllByStatus(String status);** yeah but I have seen people have used **Optional<List>** which is dangerous and inject **run time** exception.